# cakephp drop-down lists using displayed value

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

Apologies for troubling everyone with the billionth or so question about CakePHP and drop-down lists.

I have a database of employees, with fields such as name, department etc.

What I want to achieve is that the standard view of all employees can be filtered by selecting available departments and submitting a form. The departments available to select in the filter are automatically populated from the existing departments already in the database.

I'm fairly new to CakePHP, but what I'm trying to achieve is a drop-down list that is a 1 x N extract from the database. In HTML this would look like:

```
<option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
```

The idea is then to take this input and use it for a SQL query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * from Employees WHERE Department = 'finance'
```

etc.

At the moment this is the code I'm using in the controller to generate a list of all existing departments:

```
$this->set('department', $this->Employee->find('list', array('fields' => 'Employee.Department')));
```

and this I'm using this in the view to then make that into a dropdown box:

```
echo $this->Form->input('faculty', array('label' => 'Faculty', 'empty' => array('Any'), 'options' => $department));
```

The problem I am encountering is that it generates HTML along the lines of

```
<option value="1">Human Resources</option>
<option value="2">Finance</option>
```

I have read and re-read the documentation on forms and the find functions, but I can't seem to find the answer.

The only way forward I've found from that would be to manually specify the options using `array('value' => 'label')`, which given how long the full form is (and the 50+ departments we're talking about), is not something I fancy doing!

Am I:

- Missing the right option in the Form Helper or the find function?
- Just plain doing it wrong?

I know the logic for the filtering function works fine because the checkboxes are ok, and I've played around with options in the URL and if I enter it manually everything is fine.

Comment: YOu should use the Cake DC search plugin: https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Answer (score 0):

So, what I do to get an array that looks like what you want is:

```
$options = array_combine($department, $department);
echo $this->Form->input('faculty', array('label' => 'Faculty', 'empty' => array('Any'),  'options' => $options));
```

That should render something like:

```
<option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work - same result as originally described